# phonegap passing argument to storage api calls

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

According to the documentation you can create a database and populate it with:

```
 // PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    //accessToken=new Table('Token','id unique, tokenType, tokenValue');
    ///createTable(accessToken);
}


 // Populate the database

function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
     tx.executeSql(
            'INSERT INTO '+tname+' (id,data) VALUES (?, ?);',
            [id,data],
            function (transaction, resultSet) {
             //success code
             alert('sucessful insertion');
             },
             errorCB
        );
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}
```

However, is it possible for me to pass an argument to the populateDB callback in the line db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB); ? If so how would I then access the value of that argument? Please provide an example. Any help would be appreciated with this.

Answer (score 0):

The code example you have above looks a bit funky.  First, it looks like you have a javascript function in the tx.executeSql function.  This isn't possible.

Here's an example from docs.phonegap.com:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
 tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
// this will be true since it was a select statement and so rowsAffected was 0
if (!resultSet.rowsAffected) {
  console.log('No rows affected!');
  return false;
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, querySuccess);
```

The results of the callback are passed into the tx and results parameters of the callback function.

To the second part of your question, how to access the callback, it helps to understand how the callback system works.  Before making a call to the underlying device, PG creates an identifier for the call and stores references to the sucess and error callbacks.  Then, when it makes the call to the native system, it passes the identifer, **not the actual callbacks**.

If the native call is successful, cordova.successcallback will be written to the webview and passed the identifier created earlier.  If it fails, cordova.failurecallback will be written and passed the same identifier.

I highly suggest taking a look at the javascript source on github [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-js), and more specifically at the exec.js file for the particular platform you're targeting.  It will give you a better insight into how the callback system works.

Comment: can I do something like db.transaction(populateDB(somestuff),successCB, errorCB);?

Comment: I don't see why not, could you post your results after trying this?

Answer (score 0):

We can't send any argument in populateDB in "db.transaction(populateDB(somestuff),successCB, errorCB);".

transaction method will replace with tx variable.
See the source code here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-js/blob/master/lib/android/plugin/android/storage.js

Solution is provided in this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988487/905511

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, not directly as you have tried.

I use a number of defined functions when handling storage on phonegap applications that can receive parameters. A lot of the examples I have seen have calls to many sub functions and for me, this is a nightmare when it comes to debugging.

I was caught out an a number of issues around Web SQL but reading the specs really, really helped clarify what I could and couldn't do. (http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

Have a look at this code:

```
function dbInsert(param1, param2, dbObj) {
    val1 = param1;
    val2 = param2;
    val3 = String(dbObj.item2);

    var sql = "INSERT INTO DEMO (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql(sql, [val1, val2, val3])}, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

So the function takes two string parameters and a dummy object I created. These are then incorporated into an sql string which will be passed to tx.executeSql to be executed! Notice I am using ? to substitute for literals, these are sent via the parameters in the []. I am executing the tx.executeSql inside the transaction method which means it can be executed singularly and will still process the callbacks.

So for your example I would do this:

```
function dbInsert(param1, param2, dbObj) {
    val1 = param1;
    val2 = param2;
    val3 = String(dbObj.item2);

    var sql = "INSERT INTO DEMO (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql(sql, [val1, val2, val3])}, errorCB, successCB);
}

function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    dbInsert('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC');
}
```